# Saving the content of an Excel spreadsheet into a single string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read an excel spreadsheet and save it into a single string. I used pandas to read the spreadsheet and save it into a DataFrame, but I was wondering how I could convert that DataFrame into a single string with its values separated with some separator(like , ; . _ ).

This is what I have so far:

```
df = pd.read_excel(self.filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link and answer below: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html

```
a=df.to_string(index=False)
a
```

Also, to get rid of "\n", you could do this:

```
a=df.to_string(index=False).replace("\n", "")
```

Finally, you could also remove all the extra whitespace:

```
a=df.to_string(index=False).replace("\n", "")
a=" ".join(a.split())
a
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Was not expecting the answer to be this simple haha

Comment: no problem @j.doe , I also added a couple other options to get rid of whitespace, the index and /n in order to help clean up the string if you find it helpful.